Migrate pages with custom layout from Sharepoint 2013 to Sharepoint Online
Hello i tried to migrate some pages from Sharepoint 2013 to Sharepoint Online.
Those pages are using a custom layout .
This layout was deployed as a solution using .wsp.
How can i migrate pages to sharepoint online as i dont have the .wsp anymore? I already tried using Sharegate but as in Sharepoint 2013 the custom layout was developped it failed trying to migrate the pages.

You might need to rebuild those pages. As you rightly mention it is not possible to have custom layouts created by wsp on SPO.
If custom layouts have been created as content type try to migrate that first and then migrate pages.
If that doesn´t work try to pre-create custom layout using designer and then migrate.
https://sharepoint.handsontek.net/2018/02/01/create-a-page-layout-with-custom-content-areas/
Lastly you can try first modernize the pages and then migrate
https://pnp.github.io/blog/post/modernization-lives-on-in-pnp-framework/
